# How can i automate many inlet/outlet relations?

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to program a buffer to list in max msp patch.

My current solution have manual connections, but i really need to automate the process for many more patch cords.

I need a way to connect a Gate N to a Buddy N and then to a join N.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the scripting possibilities of the [thispatcher] object. That should definitely do it.

> I'm trying to program a buffer to list

if you just need to get a 'buffer to list'-thing. have a look at the patch below. Not sure this is a good idea though.

```
<pre><code>
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
990.3oc2XtrbhiCEFdM7TnxKmhgVWrElYUO6m2fo5pKYPPTGegxVNIMc08y9
HcrMPR.4KwP5LavXgP9nO8et4eLchWT1SxBOzeg9WzjI+X5jIvP1AlTe+DuD
wSqhEEvz7RkOlE8MuYU+jV9jFFVihPQMitSnWcmJc6WykqzUKNkQmimgH9g1
KLe6mT7bL5K0+G0ZXcLq8eR4MKzlrTcpHQB+zemqDwM+RZYhJMVpAihbbvrR
cynzSVjB0dXQHVqnZ3pYp+9NYkE5EIR25Mq9J5K1Y8yoSseLqirYUVRhLU+J
3jHtWh9GUg1EfBV.LIjXuvoNATvn.Hra.sIeaDLs43AvhKnSTN0HL6t1mwAM
BcdfCDv5IBnmEAjdpQTlS2AIMRJi0phX0ZYtKBvgS+fkvExBvYIbw4Q.YwwU
J2..sL+qxTQTr7zC2lcEE2eOmWs8stGCb+KKJDakuROrOdUrT3hI9bLvDJ3R
3G.jI7BHg+tnJFFRtfGx9Xz17rxcnOuO1Le6yG4iWxcJapPTUTCR.wUvCh+n
vn9Fcc3RmKvox8cIVRvR3B2IQFmXIr2R9lYugXKW.PeBQvX7bGPhQf7vrPP9
3uvIjnuKtVahyDiKV9CDYdGDNfQ0RRHB4+ILo8p2.nvH71qdif+fV81kpXIc
S1uPZo6p2pAjODtgPc5JsbT.zxAoZLDJFJD8jA5xWdSAnhJ05rz1wWcwuTrK
5E1CFQbpVFSUxNo791UI04oIvtk6LoTeqjg8aZnEyBttx2r0dCIfyC24o+3z
4CYHAWFDUdT7fbSVdxubVgaXU49Pssz.PWv8OO.NT8VT4lMx7CH3To2yHPvY
I.u0vDN9RSDjwsUfMp3XSt4YHwtcweGcuPU3rYo5pWHg.uHXtqNCXe7aLn5.
uJHC5yEhjcEF2j1ADsJqMgE5Ls86RV6CRpW6gAFoQpk9x2OErSsi+bDVjUlu
pYcadMRni600FroREZkISzwIE9r4bmZ8ZY5osOuVUX6nF3z4eMH8xbHsXNrV
LmD05cYl7vEMuzHts9TxB3BixNb2wmynsAB5.NeAyup7j0A6gvtY1isYf14y
Mzd76BeVb6rGbGz+Ddec.V.Je+pNX4KOb2UvAXYW.J41ATZWsGR2AZcLDe7o
0h.2cE.JHIZaGr71Aztjv3EtUsBzZMYP8Kk6j6tF.k0EeL+9mjw10R0qdsYG
3ecjDixQvHCTZK1ysKmm0Wf2Fcn2LyIrKGV3al4zoBBFn0TUMpoyjGj4E0KI
XHlR2+VV9gVpLNOoU2BEH6kKeP0L+PXDQtoNcsoH8x7pZreJj6M09b94z+CC
9ZL7
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
</code></pre>
```

Comment: ty Patrik :) i ve used some javascript and that worked..                                  i can show the code if you want..       i also replaced the gate with a cycle.. i does the job better.. How can i open that as a patch?

Comment: just copy everything and in max go file-> new from clipboard